# how to refer to config settings from an assembly dll added to the project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a client project which is referring to an assembly(project 2) for some additional methods which need config settings. I have set these config settings in project 2. However, project 1 does not pickup these config settings and only works if I redefine the config settings mentioned in project 2 into project 1.

Comment: The config settings must be defined in the executing assembly, .exe.config or the web.config

Comment: Thanks Kofi. As I mentioned, if I define in Project 1, it works fine. The question is, how do I get project 1 to read config settings of proj 2 for certain methods.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to have libraries control configuration settings. And I think .Net by default reads from the entry assembly's config file. You can create a Custom Settings Provider class for the .dll and then read .dll.config using a static initalizer of that class

Comment: Thanks Kofi, you are right. I created a static class to define my settings. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to have libraries control configuration settings. 
And I think .Net by default reads from the entry assembly's config file. 
You can create a Custom Settings Provider class for the .dll and then read .dll.config using a static initalizer of that class